# Why am I able to retrieve my contacts even without android.permission.READ_CONTACTS?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I write somecode to fetch all contacts,but forget to declare permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ninja.mobilehelper" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ninja.mobilehelper.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Uri contactsUri= ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] proj1=new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY};
    Cursor curContacts=getContentResolver().query(contactsUri,proj1, null, null, null);

    //declare a ArrayList object to store the data that will present to the user
    ArrayList<String> contactsList=new ArrayList<String>();
    String allPhoneNo="";
    if(curContacts.getCount()>0){
        while(curContacts.moveToNext()){
            // get all the phone numbers if exist
            if(curContacts.getInt(1)>0){
                allPhoneNo=getAllPhoneNumbers(curContacts.getString(2));
            }
            contactsList.add(curContacts.getString(0)+" , "+allPhoneNo);
            allPhoneNo="";
        }
    }

    // binding the data to ListView
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,        contactsList));
    ListView lv=getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}
```

My phone is Moto X,Android 4.4.2,uses IntelliJIdea .

Gradle builds.Android build tool version is '19.0.3'.

It seems required  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" ,But works without permission! why?!

Any suggestion?

Addition：It's my fault，I open previsously application，that declares the permission.So sad, it seems I find a bug in Android - -!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it will work if you have grant uri permission in code.

```
 grantUriPermission(getPackageName(),ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: This code, as I understand it, should be put in the Provider to allow access for other apps.  The reason I -1'd is because it suggests that this line of code is put into the onCreate of the the ListView, which I don't think is true.